# update on many-to-one hibernate relationship no works

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with hibernate relationship many-to-one.

My system is commercial proposal controller, where has a responsible for proposal from user entity. When the proposal is create and set the responsible, has no problems, works fine. But when change the responsible and update, it changes the object, I can see in a datatable, but has no update in database. If I refresh on page the update disapears.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "proposal")
    public class Proposal implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User responsible;
   ............
```

DAO Code

```
    public void update(Proposal proposal) {
    this.session.update(proposal);

    }
```

In the User class I don't make any annotation about this relationship, it's a unidirectional relationship. The class proposal yet use the user class to make a user's bag, as participants, and this relationship will be unidirectional relationship too.

I tried to make annotations in user class but no works too.

User class with annotations

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="user") 
   public class User implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany 
    private List<Proposal> proposal;
```

The class User has a many-to-one relationship with userType and it works fine.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="user") 
    public class User implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "idType, nullable = true)
     private TipoUsuario    userType;
```

Someone has any ideia about this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a JoinColumn or MappedBy annotation on either the User or Proposal class, how do you tell Hibernate how to resolve the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You'll see changes after flushing to database. Either manually - flush() or after transaction has been committed. The User class - must be either an entity (both @Entity and @Id annotations are needed) or embedable class and should be configured in the corresponding way in this case.

I'm not sure how it works if you say - @Entity without @Id for User, but try again:

1. Run flush for User. If you won't get any exception - it is a persisatble object. You should see in db/web application log files - sql insert query.
2. Commit transaction. The updated value of User should be committed.

If you invoke refresh, before commit, all your changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're missing the `@JoinColumn` annotation from your ManyToOne relationship with your User. Try updating to this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userId")
private User responsible;
```

But obviously replace 'userId' with the id name as its specified in your table.